# Selecting and Moving Only Clones From Applied Masking?

Tags: inkscape

I applied a Square Mask to a 20X20 Grid of Clones.  The squares that were under the mask are now gray.  Before I applied the mask I unlinked all the clones.  I'm trying to move the gray squares using Right Click > Select Same > Fill Color.  However this also selects all the other squares that were outside the mask.  This is an image:
[image]

How can we select and move only the gray squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The masked out squares are still the same colour, just hidden behind the mask. That's why Select Same is selecting them.

Instead, use the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (F2) to select them by clicking and dragging a selection only around the squares you want to select, or select them manually by clicking on each one while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Switch back to the Select Tool (F1), then you can move them inside the mask, delete/cut them etc.

[image]

Comment: Deselecting, then using Shift+Click+Drag with the selection tool will achieve the same, btw.

Comment: @Moini Yes, there are many ways to skin a cat.